# NX build affected does not fail in GitHub workflow pipeline (but does locally)

Tags: angular, typescript, github-actions, nx.dev

An NX/Angular project has a [PR](https://github.com/sneat-co/sneat-apps/pull/1506) that passes build validation but it should not.

The command is running in [Github workflow](https://github.com/sneat-co/sneat-apps/blob/main/.github/workflows/build.yml):

```
pnpm run nx affected --target=build --base=${{ env.NX_BASE }} --parallel=0 --maxParallel=1
```

Outputs: `>  NX   Successfully ran target build for 43 projects`

But locally the same fails and returns:

```
 >  NX   Ran target build for 43 projects
```

I'd expect the pipeline fail for this PR as Angular does not support TypeScript 5.2.2

What could be the root cause and how to make NX build to properly fail as expected?

Comment: How do you run it locally? What does your local env look like? Have you looked at the [preinstalled software](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md) on `ubuntu-latest` that may be interfering with your build (i.e. making it different compared to your local env) e.g. you're using NodeJS v16? You may consider using [`jobs.<job_id>.container`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer) to isolate this build.